# EXC_SOFTWARE / UNCAUGHT_NS_EXCEPTION

Tags: ios, swift, crash-reports

I have a crash occurring in life app which I can not reproduce on my devices. I have not been able to figure out what causes it. I studied to crash report but seem not to be able to understand what is causing this.

```
1 CoreFoundation __exceptionPreprocess + 1241536
2 libobjc.A.dylib objc_exception_throw + 34136
3 CoreFoundation -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 1270388
4 CoreFoundation ___forwarding___ + 1258100
5 CoreFoundation _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 185752
6 GLKit -[GLKViewController setPaused:] + 144836
7 GLKit -[GLKViewController _pauseByNotification] + 142828
8 CoreFoundation __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 823848
9 CoreFoundation _CFXRegistrationPost + 821548
10 CoreFoundation ___CFXNotificationPost_block_invoke + 820904
11 CoreFoundation -[_CFXNotificationRegistrar find:object:observer:enumerator:] + 1276824
12 CoreFoundation _CFXNotificationPost + 44016
13 Foundation -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 26152
14 UIKit -[UIApplication _deactivateForReason:notify:] + 491392
15 UIKit __61-[UIApplication _sceneSettingsPreLifecycleEventDiffInspector]_block_invoke + 2711892
16 FrontBoardServices __52-[FBSSettingsDiffInspector inspectDiff:withContext:]_block_invoke.27 + 144868
17 Foundation __NSIndexSetEnumerate + 788368
18 BaseBoard -[BSSettingsDiff inspectChangesWithBlock:] + 208636
19 FrontBoardServices -[FBSSettingsDiff inspectOtherChangesWithBlock:] + 120484
20 FrontBoardServices -[FBSSettingsDiffInspector inspectDiff:withContext:] + 144320
21 UIKit __70-[UIApplication scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 2717116
22 UIKit -[UIApplication scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:] + 2716256
23 UIKit -[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:handleEvent:withCompletion:] + 6065056
24 FrontBoardServices __80-[FBSSceneImpl updater:didUpdateSettings:withDiff:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke.376 + 52104
25 FrontBoardServices __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 239800
26 FrontBoardServices -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 239396
27 FrontBoardServices -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 240332
28 CoreFoundation __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 905844
29 CoreFoundation __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 904124
30 CoreFoundation __CFRunLoopRun + 894908
31 CoreFoundation CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 36932
32 GraphicsServices GSEventRunModal + 49556
33 UIKit -[UIApplication _run] + 504568
34 UIKit UIApplicationMain + 483376
35 XXX main (XXXViewController.swift:14)
36 libdyld.dylib
start + 17844
```

Line 35 (only mention of code I wrote) is the XXXViewController class definition line:

```
class XXXViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
...
}
```

This ViewController calls an observer, which seems to be the problem. I am making sure the I remove all observers in the ViewControllers that use them in the deinit function.

```
deinit {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
}
```

Does anybody have an idea what else could be going wrong?

UPDATE:
I register the observer like this ini init() (should I use viewDidLoad instead?):

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector:#selector(YViewController.dataUpdate(_:)), name: "DataChanged", object: nil)
```

and post the notification like this:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("DataChanged", object: self, userInfo: nil)
```

The YViewController dataUpdate is as follows:

```
func dataUpdate(notification: NSNotification) {
    //Some stuff is done
}
```

I use swift 2.0 for now and the crash has happened on iOS version 10.0.1-10.1.1

Comment: Would it be possible to show your `postNotification` and the `addObserver` calls?

Comment: Also, what version of Swift are you using?

Comment: And ios-versions on the devices.

Comment: @RyanH. I updated to question. Thanks for looking at it.

Comment: @kometen I updated the question. Thanks for looking at it.

Comment: is this just a flaw in firebase crash reporting that it's not offering up enough information to trace? I have 2 crashes in a production React Native app like this.

Comment: Just in case anybody lands here. The problem was that I was overwritting the base view of the GLKViewController instead of adding the new view as a subview. This became easily clear, when I switched to Crashlytics.

Comment: @dk_dev, you can post an answer to your own question explaining how did you find out what the problem was and how did you fix it. It would be much more visible for future visitors than a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anybody lands here. The problem was that I was overwriting the base view of the GLKViewController instead of adding the new view as a subview. This became easily clear, when I switched to Crashlytics, which had more information about the crash.